# How to reset pedometer to 0 in Swift? I am using CMPedometer()

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

I want to add a button in my app and reset the pedometer to 0 by pressing it. Now I just finish a common pedometer, my code is below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var step: UILabel!

    var days:[String] = []
    var stepsTaken:[Int] = []
    let activityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
    var pedoMeter = CMPedometer()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var cal  = Calendar.current
        var comps = cal.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
        comps.hour = 0
        comps.minute = 0
        comps.second = 0
        let timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
        cal.timeZone = timeZone
        let midnight = cal.date(from: comps)!

        if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){


            self.pedoMeter.startUpdates(from: midnight) { (data: CMPedometerData?, error) -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    if(error == nil){
                        self.step.text = "\(data!.numberOfSteps)"
                    }
                })
            }
        }    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "reset the pedometer". It is a piece of hardware.

What *you* do is write *software*. No law says that you have to maintain or display as *your* count the same number that the pedometer is keeping as *its* count. Maintain your own separate count as an instance property.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question, how can I start the count from 0 again after pressing the button?

Comment: As I said, _your_ count can be anything you want. So set _your_ count to 0.

Answer (score 0):

About 5 years late, but you can actually "reset" the pedometer to a zero state by just restarting it with Date(). Keep in mind you aren't actually resetting the devices pedometer, you can't do that, but you are resetting the data stream that you receive from it. Hope this helps someone :)

```swift
CMPedometer().startUpdates(from: Date())
```

If you want historical steps to count you can start from a date in the past

```swift
CMPedometer().startUpdates(from: somePastDate)
```